# Grouping of similer nodes

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have follwing problem in grouping the similer nodes with xsl:

input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<concept id="ads">
    <p>para1 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>1</Bullet>
    <Bullet>2</Bullet>
    <Bullet>3</Bullet>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>4</Bullet>
    <Bullet>5</Bullet>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
</concept>
```

Output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<concept id="ads">
    <p>para1 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
</concept>
```

All the "Bullet" element which does not have imideate preceding sibling as "Bullet" should wrap up in "UL" and "Li" elements.

I am trying something like this but not able to achive the result:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Bullet[not(preceding-sibling::Bullet)]">
<ul>
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
<xsl:variable name="current-name" select="generate-id(.)"/>
<xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::*[Bullet][generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[Bullet]) = $current-name]">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please help.

---Related Question ----

This works fine on given xml input, but 
1. In my actual xml these `<Bullet>` tags can appear anywhere under concept node, so grouping with `<p>` element does not work in that case.

1. Currently I am processing all the nodes except "Bullet" nodes, so i need to match only `<Bullet>` nodes which is having immediate following sibling as `<Bullet>` and wrap the sequence in `<ul>` and each `<Bullet>` in `<li>`. My current context node is `<concept>`.
2. Current stylesheet  as follows:

   nodes which should render at the same place as in input.-->

Actual XML pattern:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<concept id="ads"> 
    <p>para1 content goes here</p> 
    <Body-text>Body1 content goes here</Body-text>
    <Bullet>1</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>2</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>3</Bullet> 
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p> 
    <Bullet>4</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>5</Bullet> 
    <p>para3 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>6</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>7</Bullet> 
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <Bullet>6</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>7</Bullet> 
</concept>
<concept id="ads"> 
    <p>para1 content goes here</p> 
    <Body-text>Body1 content goes here</Body-text>
    <Bullet>1</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>2</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>3</Bullet> 
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p> 
    <Bullet>4</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>5</Bullet> 
    <p>para3 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>6</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>7</Bullet> 
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <Bullet>6</Bullet> 
    <Bullet>7</Bullet> 
</concept>
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a genuine XSLT 2.0 solution.

Comment: So, what should be the expected result on the longer XML document?

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Bullet[preceding-sibling::node()[1]
                               [not(self::Bullet)]]">
        <ul>
            <xsl:call-template name="makeLi"/>
        </ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                                     [not(self::Bullet)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Bullet" name="makeLi">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]
                                                              [self::Bullet]"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: Just changing the following applying "first `Bullet`" rule to first next not `Bullet` instead of `p`.

Output (wrapping your input with root element to be wellformed):

```
<concept id="ads">
    <p>para1 content goes here</p>
    <Body-text>Body1 content goes here</Body-text>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <p>para3 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
    </ul>
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
    </ul>
</concept>
<concept id="ads">
    <p>para1 content goes here</p>
    <Body-text>Body1 content goes here</Body-text>
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
    </ul>
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
    <p>para3 content goes here</p>
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
    </ul>
    <Body-text>Body2 content goes here</Body-text>
    <ul>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
    </ul>
</concept>
```

**Note**: Fine grained traversal.

With grouping, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="concept">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" 
                                group-adjacent="boolean(self::Bullet)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <ul>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </ul>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Bullet">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: Ussing `group-adjacent`.

Comment: please ignore my previous comment: I have edited my question, I would be thankful if you look at the updated problem and let me know your comment on that.

Comment: Thanks again Alejendro, You saved my week!

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p">
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]"/>
           <xsl:if test="current-group()[2]">
               <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position() gt 1]"/>
              </ul>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Bullet">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<concept id="ads">
    <p>para1 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>1</Bullet>
    <Bullet>2</Bullet>
    <Bullet>3</Bullet>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
    <Bullet>4</Bullet>
    <Bullet>5</Bullet>
    <p>para2 content goes here</p>
</concept>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<concept id="ads">
   <p>para1 content goes here</p>
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
   </ul>
   <p>para2 content goes here</p>
   <ul>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
   </ul>
   <p>para2 content goes here</p>
</concept>
```

**Do note**: The use of `<xsl:for-each-group>` with the `group-starting-with` attribute and the `current-group()` function.

Comment: +1 I like this current group position test, it's a shorter expression so you don't have to put it in a variable for compacting the code. But, I must say that besides that is the same solution. The "genuine" comparison... it's to much, ja!

Comment: @Alejandro: By "genuine" I meant: "one that exploits as many XSLT 2.0 relevant to grouping features, as possible". And we both know what I mean: no keys, `<xsl:for-each-group>`, the `group-starting-with` attribute, `current-group()`